# What exactly does the Gmail `list:` filter selector do?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search, mailing-list

I am moving some of my mailing list inboxes from a private system to Gmail where I want the list messages to go into separate "list inbox" folders, rather than the main inbox. I started by bouncing a list message from the other system to Gmail and, when I went to set up a filter for the bounced message, Gmail seemed to recognise that this was a message to a list and suggested a filter in the "Has the words" field of `list:(x.x.jp)`. (The list sends messages to `x@x.jp`; I've changed the name of the list itself here to `x`.)

What exactly does this match in messages? My instinct would have been to put `x@x.jp` email address in the "To" line of the form (where I presume it would match against both the `To:` and `Cc:` headers).

(Edit: The rule from the match suggested to me seems to exhibiting some odd behaviour as well; the action is `Skip Inbox, Apply label "__Inboxes/x"`, and no other rules apply that label, yet some of the messages I've bounced since have both `Inbox` and `__Inboxes/x` labels.)

The only place I've seen this mentioned in previous questions is in [Filtering Apache mailing list emails in Gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/12912/122113), which makes it clear that the feature is at least ten years old, but does not explain how it works. The answer to that question also uses `x@x.jp` syntax rather than the `x.x.jp` syntax that was suggested to me by Google.

Other questions that address mailing list detection in Gmail but don't mention `list:` at all are [2962](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2962/122113), [17271](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/17271/122113) and [28159](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/28159/122113).

Answer (score 1):

It may be using the `List-Id` header. In this case, the messages have `List-Id: Y Z Users Group <x.x.jp>` headers in them, which explains the `x.x` versus `x@x` difference from the "Filtering Apache" Q&A.